# Converting a hex number into a negative one in R

Tags: r, string, printing, hex

I wanted to print a negative number using `sprintf`:
`x <- 5`,
`sprintf("%x is a negative number", x)` and the result is the following one: `"fffffffb is a negative number"`.
Then I tried to use separately `strtoi()` to convert the hex value:
`strtoi("0xfffffffb", base=32L)` and the result was: [1] NA.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. `%x` displays integers as hexadecimal numbers. It doesnot create the output you claim it does if you use 5 as input. Why are you not using `%d` or `%f`?

Comment: You might want to study `help("sprintf")`.